# Bulk Export.Decompress stored data stored in table and save it to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, powershell, compression

I am after a shell script or an SQL Query for the following.

I need to export a set of records, from a column, which are compressed. I need to decompress each record and save the record on to a XML file and rename each file separately. I have about 21K records to be decompressed and saved.

I have tried to decompress one such file with the below query -
declare @xS varbinary(max)

SELECT @xs = [xml]
  FROM [mil].[V2_MIL_XmlStore]
  where XmlStoreId IN ('41234687')

select @xS [test]
  --return

select [dbo].V2_SQLCLR_DeCompressByteArray

But it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Hi, can You please give some reference as to what "compressed record" is?

Comment: 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

Comment: the above seen is the compressed record stored on to the system. All XML files received are stored on to a column and the files are deleted. Now, i am in a situation to retrieve the data, i.e decompress these compressed records, put them back into XML and rename the XML with a filename provided in the file. Bit too complex for me, any suggestions ?